# Do Timers restart "for loops"? I am trying to make a timer the cause a panel to cycle through 5 different colors at a set interval of time

Tags: java

```
public class TimerListener implements ActionListener
    {
        private JPanel focus;
        Color colorWheel[] = new Color[5];
        public TimerListener(JPanel p)
        {
            focus = p;

            colorWheel[0] = Color.RED;
            colorWheel[1] = Color.BLUE;
            colorWheel[2] = Color.YELLOW;
            colorWheel[3] = Color.GREEN;
            colorWheel[4] = Color.ORANGE;

        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {

            for(int i = 0; i < colorWheel.length; i++)
            {
                focus.setBackground(colorWheel[i]);
                focus.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'Do Timers restart “for loops”?' No, timers execute `run()` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop will "reset" itself. This is because, when you declare your counter `i`, it exists within the scope of the `for loop`. When the `for loop` ends, `i` ceases to exist.

Comment: Right. So how would i make it so a timer can have a panel cycle through the same 5 colors in order until the timer calls the "stop()" method?

Comment: Use a `while` loop, with a `boolean` flag to indicate whether to keep running or not.

Comment: I originally tried using a while loop but it seemed like it kept freezing the JFrame. It wouldn't close and it never actually repainted the panel either.